# K8S Init Container CRD/Operator

Tags: kubernetes

I want to inject an init container into some pods. I know how to specify init containers in a pod's spec, but I don't want to do that directly because these sidecars are invisible to my engineers.

I don't want to go through the complexity of developing my own mutating web hook or operator, so does anyone know of a good package/service that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Eventually, I went with [OpenKruise](https://openkruise.io/), which is a pretty simple but cool open-source framework for, amongst other things, creating a centralised way of managing sidecars and init-containers in a cluster, without needing to concern application developers.

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr and Salesforce have open sourced their generic injectors:

- https://github.com/tumblr/k8s-sidecar-injector
- https://github.com/salesforce/generic-sidecar-injector

Both of these should fit your simple use case but offer a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out